# NEW MEMBER USER AGREEMENT

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams, microsoft

I am fairly new to Microsoft teams.  I am wondering if there is a way to set up a user agreement form or page for new members/guests.  Ideally I would invite someone to a team and they would be required to read the terms and conditions and agree them before being granted access to the team.  Is this possible and if so what is the correct way to go about doing so?

Answer (score 0):

Did you connect to teams from the SharePoint site? If so, you can try to add a member to the SharePoint site and grant him the corresponding permissions.

[image]

For more information about permissions, you could refer to [SharePoint site permissions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/customize-sharepoint-site-permissions).

And here is a blog about Microsoft Teams and SharePoint permissions you could have a look:
[Microsoft Teams and SharePoint permissions explained](https://engagesq.com/microsoft-teams-and-sharepoint-permissions-explained/)